# Why is my bubble sort code printing out this weird stuff?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, printing

Ok, so here's my code. I think it should work fine to sort those numbers in the array. However, every time I attempt to run it, all it does is print "[I@178af9c0" or some weird variation on that. I have absolutely no idea what do about this and would appreciate any help that you can give me. Thank you very much!!!

```
public class BubbleSort {



    public void Print(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        int[] BubbleSort = {3, 4, 1, 2};    
            int lengthOfArray = BubbleSort.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray - 1; i++){
                for (int n = 1; n < lengthOfArray - i; n++){
                    if (BubbleSort[n - 1] > BubbleSort[n]){
                         Swap(i, n , BubbleSort);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(BubbleSort.toString());  
    }



     private static void Swap(int index1, int index2, int[] array) {       
         int temp;
         temp = array[index1];
         array[index1] = array[index2];
         array[index2] = temp;
     }
}
```

Comment: Also, are there any glaring problems with my code?

Comment: You are trying to print the array, System.out.println(BubbleSort.toString());

you should actually print the items contained in the array 

for(i=0;i<BubbleSort.length()-1;i++)
{
System.out.print( BubbleSort[i])
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, arrays are classes.  So that string is the reference to the array, not the contents of the array.  If you want to print the contents, probably the easiest way is to iterate over all the elements.

```
for(int  i : BubbleSort)  System.out.println(""+i);
```

(Tested on Java 8, twiddle for your version of Java.)

There are some logic errors in there, but as this looks like a homework question, I'll just mention that you are heading down the right lines, but may need to pencil out what you're actually doing and draw the flow.

Answer (score 0):

To get a String representation of an Array, you can use `Arrays.toString(yourArray);`